# How to sort in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I find no documentation for the sort modifier. The only insight is in the unit tests:
[spec.lib.query.js#L12](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/13d957f6e54d6a0b358ea61cf9437699079fd2d9/tests/unit/spec.lib.query.js#L12)

```
writer.limit(5).sort(['test', 1]).group('name')
```

But it doesn't work for me:

```
Post.find().sort(['updatedAt', 1]);
```

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15081087/938236) for an up to day answer.

Answer (score 243):

In Mongoose, a sort can be done in any of the following ways:

```js
    Post.find({}).sort('test').exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
    Post.find({}).sort([['date', -1]]).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
    Post.find({}).sort({test: 1}).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
    Post.find({}, null, {sort: {date: 1}}, function(err, docs) { ... });
```

Comment: This is almost a straight copy of the answer linked by Francisco Presencia. Unfortunately the highest voted answers are outdated and unnecessarily long.

Comment: This is not quite correct as of today. `{sort: [['date', 1]]}` will not work, but  `.sort([['date', -1]])` will work. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15081087/404699

Comment: @steampowered thanks, i'll make an edit, you are very welcome to let me know or edit if I got it wrong.

Comment: Would love to see a few remarks on what the result is, esp. what the `1` and `-1` values mean, instead of having 4 code lines without much context

Answer (score 162):

This is how I got sort to work in mongoose 2.3.0 :)

```
// Find First 10 News Items
News.find({
    deal_id:deal._id // Search Filters
},
['type','date_added'], // Columns to Return
{
    skip:0, // Starting Row
    limit:10, // Ending Row
    sort:{
        date_added: -1 //Sort by Date Added DESC
    }
},
function(err,allNews){
    socket.emit('news-load', allNews); // Do something with the array of 10 objects
})
```

Comment: in mongoose 3 you can't use `Array` for field selection anymore - it has to be `String` or `Object`

Comment: btw, if you want all fields, you can just pull `null` in that section (at least in 3.8)

Answer (score 108):

As of Mongoose 3.8.x:

```js
model.find({ ... }).sort({ field : criteria}).exec(function(err, model){ ... });
```

**Where:**

`criteria` can be `asc`, `desc`, `ascending`, `descending`, `1`, or `-1`

**Note: Use quotation marks or double quote**

use `"asc"`, `"desc"`, `"ascending"`, `"descending"`, `1`, or `-1`

Answer (score 78):

UPDATE:

```js
Post.find().sort({'updatedAt': -1}).all((posts) => {
  // do something with the array of posts
});
```

---

Try:

```js
Post.find().sort([['updatedAt', 'descending']]).all((posts) => {
  // do something with the array of posts
});
```

Comment: In the latest Mongoose (2.4.10) it's `.sort("updatedAt", -1)`.

Comment: In the even more latest Mongoose (3.5.6-pre, but I'm pretty sure it's valid for all of 3.x) it's `.sort({updatedAt: -1})` or `.sort('-updatedAt')`.

Comment: Then you should use `exec(function (posts) {…` instead of `all`

Comment: I've got a `all() must be used after where() when called with these arguments` in Mongoose 4.6.5...

Comment: I use this in Node.js like
```javascript
Post.find().sort({updatedAt: -1}).all((posts) => {
```

Answer (score 51):

**Mongoose v5.x.x**

sort by ascending order

```
Post.find({}).sort('field').exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Post.find({}).sort({ field: 'asc' }).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Post.find({}).sort({ field: 'ascending' }).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Post.find({}).sort({ field: 1 }).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });

Post.find({}, null, {sort: { field : 'asc' }}), function(err, docs) { ... });
Post.find({}, null, {sort: { field : 'ascending' }}), function(err, docs) { ... });
Post.find({}, null, {sort: { field : 1 }}), function(err, docs) { ... });
```

sort by descending order

```
Post.find({}).sort('-field').exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Post.find({}).sort({ field: 'desc' }).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Post.find({}).sort({ field: 'descending' }).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Post.find({}).sort({ field: -1 }).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });


Post.find({}, null, {sort: { field : 'desc' }}), function(err, docs) { ... });
Post.find({}, null, {sort: { field : 'descending' }}), function(err, docs) { ... });
Post.find({}, null, {sort: { field : -1 }}), function(err, docs) { ... });
```

For Details: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort

Comment: As @Sunny Sultan  pointed portend out all `Post.find({}, null, {sort: '-field'}, function(err, docs) { ... });` for descending and `Post.find({}, null, {sort: 'field'}, function(err, docs) { ... });` for ascending work as well. In Fact as I pass the field and sort order in the http query parameters, combining them into a string and use this way to sort my bd query is my only option.

Answer (score 24):

**Update**

There is a better write up if this is confusing people; check out [finding documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/finding-documents.html) and [how queries work](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/query.html) in the mongoose manual. If you want to use the fluent api you can get a query object by not providing a callback to the `find()` method, otherwise you can specify the parameters as I outline below.

**Original**

Given a `model` object, per the [docs on Model](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html), this is how it can work for `2.4.1`:

```
Post.find({search-spec}, [return field array], {options}, callback)
```

The `search spec` expects an object, but you can pass `null` or an empty object.

The second param is the field list as an array of strings, so you would supply `['field','field2']` or `null`.

The third param is the options as an object, which includes the ability to sort the result set. You would use `{ sort: { field: direction } }` where `field` is the string fieldname `test` (in your case) and `direction` is a number where `1` is ascending and `-1` is desceding.

The final param (`callback`) is the callback function which receives the collection of docs returned by the query.

The `Model.find()` implementation (at this version) does a sliding allocation of properties to handle optional params (which is what confused me!):

```
Model.find = function find (conditions, fields, options, callback) {
  if ('function' == typeof conditions) {
    callback = conditions;
    conditions = {};
    fields = null;
    options = null;
  } else if ('function' == typeof fields) {
    callback = fields;
    fields = null;
    options = null;
  } else if ('function' == typeof options) {
    callback = options;
    options = null;
  }

  var query = new Query(conditions, options).select(fields).bind(this, 'find');

  if ('undefined' === typeof callback)
    return query;

  this._applyNamedScope(query);
  return query.find(callback);
};
```

HTH

Comment: for projection : we need to provide string that contains column names seperated with space.

Answer (score 18):

you can sort your query results by

```html
Post.find().sort({createdAt: "descending"});
```

Answer (score 12):

This is how I got sort to work in mongoose.js 2.0.4

```
var query = EmailModel.find({domain:"gmail.com"});
query.sort('priority', 1);
query.exec(function(error, docs){
  //...
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Chaining with the query builder interface in Mongoose 4.

```
// Build up a query using chaining syntax. Since no callback is passed this will create an instance of Query.
var query = Person.
    find({ occupation: /host/ }).
    where('name.last').equals('Ghost'). // find each Person with a last name matching 'Ghost'
    where('age').gt(17).lt(66).
    where('likes').in(['vaporizing', 'talking']).
    limit(10).
    sort('-occupation'). // sort by occupation in decreasing order
    select('name occupation'); // selecting the `name` and `occupation` fields


// Excute the query at a later time.
query.exec(function (err, person) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log('%s %s is a %s.', person.name.first, person.name.last, person.occupation) // Space Ghost is a talk show host
})
```

See the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) for more about queries.

Answer (score 7):

```
app.get('/getting',function(req,res){
    Blog.find({}).limit(4).skip(2).sort({age:-1}).then((resu)=>{
        res.send(resu);
        console.log(resu)
        // console.log(result)
    })
})
```

Output

```
[ { _id: 5c2eec3b8d6e5c20ed2f040e, name: 'e', age: 5, __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5c2eec0c8d6e5c20ed2f040d, name: 'd', age: 4, __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5c2eec048d6e5c20ed2f040c, name: 'c', age: 3, __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5c2eebf48d6e5c20ed2f040b, name: 'b', age: 2, __v: 0 } ]
```

Answer (score 5):

with the current version of mongoose (1.6.0) if you only want to sort by **one** column, you have to drop the array and pass the object directly to the sort() function:

```
Content.find().sort('created', 'descending').execFind( ... );
```

took me some time, to get this right :(

Answer (score 4):

This is how I managed to sort and populate:

```
Model.find()
.sort('date', -1)
.populate('authors')
.exec(function(err, docs) {
    // code here
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Post.find().sort({updatedAt: 1});
```

Answer (score 3):

As of October 2020, to fix your issue you should add .exec() to the call. don't forget that if you want to use this data outside of the call you should run something like this inside of an async function.

```
let post = await callQuery();

async function callQuery() {
      return Post.find().sort(['updatedAt', 1].exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Others worked for me, but this did:

```
  Tag.find().sort('name', 1).run(onComplete);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Post.find().sort({updatedAt:1}).exec(function (err, posts){
...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from 4.x the sort methods have been changed. If you are using >4.x. Try using any of the following.

```
Post.find({}).sort('-date').exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Post.find({}).sort({date: -1}).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Post.find({}).sort({date: 'desc'}).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Post.find({}).sort({date: 'descending'}).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Post.find({}).sort([['date', -1]]).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Post.find({}, null, {sort: '-date'}, function(err, docs) { ... });
Post.find({}, null, {sort: {date: -1}}, function(err, docs) { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what i did, it works fine.

```
User.find({name:'Thava'}, null, {sort: { name : 1 }})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Ascending with updatedAt field
Post.find().sort('updatedAt').exec((err, post) => {...});

// Descending with updatedAt field
Post.find().sort('-updatedAt').exec((err, post) => {...});
```

Refer here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community. While your answer may provide a solution, a good answer requires some explanation. Kindly add some references and a proper explanation.

Comment: Reference in here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Answer (score 0):

you can also use aggregate() for sorting

```
 const sortBy = req.params.sort;
  const limitNum = req.params.limit;
  const posts = await Post.aggregate([
    { $unset: ['field-1', 'field-2', 'field-3', 'field-4'] },
    { $match: { field-1: value} },
    { $sort: { [sortBy]: -1 } },  //-------------------> sort the result
    { $limit: Number(limitNum) },
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
posts.find().sort({field:1})
```

// for ascending and for descending order just use -1 instead of 1