# In Mongoose, how do I sort by date? (node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

let's say I run this query in Mongoose:

```js
    Room.find({}, (err,docs) => {
    
    }).sort({date:-1});
```

This doesn't work!

Answer (score 562, accepted):

[Sorting](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort) in Mongoose has evolved over the releases such that some of these answers are no longer valid. As of the **4.1.x** release of Mongoose, a descending sort on the `date` field can be done in any of the following ways:

```
    Room.find({}).sort('-date').exec((err, docs) => { ... });
    Room.find({}).sort({date: -1}).exec((err, docs) => { ... });
    Room.find({}).sort({date: 'desc'}).exec((err, docs) => { ... });
    Room.find({}).sort({date: 'descending'}).exec((err, docs) => { ... });
    Room.find({}).sort([['date', -1]]).exec((err, docs) => { ... });
    Room.find({}, null, {sort: '-date'}, (err, docs) => { ... });
    Room.find({}, null, {sort: {date: -1}}, (err, docs) => { ... });
```

For an ascending sort, omit the `-` prefix on the string version or use values of `1`, `asc`, or `ascending`.

Comment: +1 for showing tons of different ways it can be done. However, I can't find in the docs that [Query#find](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find) will take that many arguments. The signature is `Query#find([criteria], [callback])`. I thought maybe there was some secret handshake that says "criteria" can be up to three arguments, but it lists the type as "Object".

Comment: @Nateowami You're looking at the wrong `find` method in the docs. See [`Model.find`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find).

Comment: You're right. I saw they were using the `Module#property` notation and searched for `#find`. It seems there is no easy way to navigate or search the docs. Searching for find yields 187 results.

Comment: You can also sort by the `_id` field. For example, to get the most recent record, you can do: `await db.collection.findOne().sort({ _id: -1 });`

Answer (score 59):

The correct answer is:

```
Blah.find({}).sort({date: -1}).execFind(function(err,docs){

});
```

Comment: the updated sort syntax for the example above is: sort('-date') http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort

Comment: This one did not work for me. I am getting an error "User.find(...).sort(...).execFind is not a function"

Answer (score 17):

Been dealing with this issue today using Mongoose 3.5(.2) and none of the answers quite helped me solve this issue. The following code snippet does the trick

```
Post.find().sort('-posted').find(function (err, posts) {
    // user posts array
});
```

You can send any standard parameters you need to `find()` (e.g. where clauses and return fields) but **no** callback. Without a callback it returns a Query object which you chain `sort()` on. You need to call `find()` again (with or without more parameters -- shouldn't need any for efficiency reasons) which will allow you to get the result set in your callback.

Answer (score 9):

```
Post.find().sort({date:-1}, function(err, posts){
});
```

Should work as well

**EDIT:**

You can also try using this if you get the error `sort() only takes 1 Argument` :

```
Post.find({}, {
    '_id': 0,    // select keys to return here
}, {sort: '-date'}, function(err, posts) {
    // use it here
});
```

Comment: this gives me the error: `Error: sort() only takes 1 Argument
`

Comment: @LukeXF please see the updated answer. i hope it helps you :)

Comment: @mrid it should be like:

`Post.find({}, {'_id': 0}).sort("-date").function(err, posts){});`

Answer (score 4):

I do this:

```
Data.find( { $query: { user: req.user }, $orderby: { dateAdded: -1 } } function ( results ) {
    ...
})
```

This will show the most recent things first.

Comment: [`$orderby`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/) is deprecated in MongoDB 3.2 so it shouldn't be used anymore.

Answer (score 3):

All the anwsers here are factually correct, however I am writing my anwser to make it clear that sometimes writing '-date' or date: -1 won't work if you either don't have a field named 'date' in your model, or if you passed the option: timestamps: true in options when creating your model. If you are using **timestamps: true** then you need to type: **sort({createdAt: -1})** and this will work then.

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps > [How to sort in mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299991/how-to-sort-in-mongoose)

Also read this > http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order

Comment: That 1st method doesn't work. It just hangs...I think it's because

of an update in mongoose.... And the 2nd method is just the mongo docs, which I know about.

Comment: The find() function is MongoDB's function, not Mongoose. Please read Mongoose API page for more details You can use the syntax defined in MongoDB docs with Mongoose. That's why Mongoose doesn't have its own sorting or intersect queries.

Answer (score 2):

Short solution:

```
const query = {}
const projection = {}
const options = { sort: { id: 1 }, limit: 2, skip: 10 }

Room.find(query, projection, options).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also sort by the `_id` field. For example, to get the most recent record, you can do,

```
const mostRecentRecord = await db.collection.findOne().sort({ _id: -1 });
```

It's much quicker too, because I'm more than willing to bet that your `date` field is not indexed.

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me.

```
`Post.find().sort({postedon: -1}).find(function (err, sortedposts){
    if (err) 
        return res.status(500).send({ message: "No Posts." });
    res.status(200).send({sortedposts : sortedposts});
 });`
```

Answer (score 2):

ES6 solution with Koa.

```
  async recent() {
    data = await ReadSchema.find({}, { sort: 'created_at' });
    ctx.body = data;
  }
```