# Sorting a Subdocument in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I am attempting to sort output from Mongoose by a date, which is stored in a subdocument. I believe this could be done more easily on the client-side, but I want to limit the draw on server resources and lazyload the subdocuments rather than just loading them all at once.

I'm working on a private messaging feature. I have a schema called Conversations defined, and I have another schema called messages defined. Their code is as follows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ChatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    messageBody: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    from: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true // Saves createdAt and updatedAt as dates. createdAt will be our timestamp.
  });

const ConversationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  participants: [String],
  messages: [ChatSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Chat', ChatSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Conversation', ConversationSchema);
```

The messages save just fine, and the information seems to be stored correctly in the database. My problem comes when I try to use the cursor.sort() method to return the most recent messages first. The query (code to follow) returns one message, as is intended, but I cannot get it to return the most recent message.

```
exports.getConversations = function(req, res, next) {
  // Only return one message from each conversation to display as snippet
  Conversation.find({ participants: req.user._id })
  .sort('-messages.createdAt')
  .slice('messages', 1).exec(function(err, conversations) {
    if (err) {
      res.send({ error: err });
      return next(err);
    } // other code...
```

I have tried every variation of sort I found in this post to no avail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15081087/5956144

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to wrestle with an ORM (a slow and poorly documented one at that) to sort an array of objects by a nested property. Put on your awesome-pants, roll your own sort function, and call it a day.

```
function byMessageCreatedAt(a, b){
    //modify the below comparison however you need to to compare two times
    return a.messages.createdAt - b.messages.createdAt
}

var results = conversation.find({blah}).sort(byMessageCreatedAt);
```

Details on sorting in javascript found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: One of the things I am trying to avoid is the overhead of requesting all the messages for each conversation. If there were hundreds, or thousands of messages in a conversation, and that was getting pulled every time a user visited their inbox, that would be pretty inefficient, right? Maybe I am wrong. It just seems like there should be a better way to do something so trivial. I have since tried aggregates. Those got me close, but didn't get me all the way there either, as I couldn't filter down the results with a .find() or .select().

Comment: To be clear: sorting via the syntax provided by mongoose is just syntactical sugar. Regardless of the method of sorting you use, you are still sorting over the result set each time. Your comment is a completely different question than your original. Your original question was "how to sort results of a query". Now you're asking "how do I limit the result set".