# Sort Mongodb data by price

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, search, mongoose

Goal: I'm trying to find a way to let a user sort rentals by max and min price on the one index page.

My problem is the only way I could figure out how to make it work was to create two separate pages specifically for lowprice and highprice. I want to only have one main index.

The pricelow page shown below filters the data from low to high prices

```
        app.get("/pricelow", function(req, res){
        Listings.find({}).sort({price: 1}).exec(function(err, allListings){
               if(err){
                   console.log(err);
               } else {
               res.render("pricelow",{listings:allListings});
               }
          })
    });
```

//The pricehigh page shown below filters the data from high to low prices

```
app.get("/pricehigh", function(req, res){
    Listings.find({}).sort({price: -1}).exec(function(err, allListings){
               if(err){
                   console.log(err);
               } else {
               res.render("pricehigh",{listings:allListings});
               }
          })
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you probably noticed, the only difference between both codes is the `sort()` condition.

Luckily for you, sorting can be done in [multiple ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15081087/1022914).

IMO the easiest way is to pass a string e.g. `price` (ascending) or `-price` (descending) via query parameter.

Merge both route handlers into one

```
app.get('/rentals', function (req, res) {
    Listings.find({}).sort(req.query.sort).exec(function (err, listings) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render('rentals', { listings: listings });
        }
    })
});
```

When you sort, call `/rentals?sort=price` or `/rentals?sort=-price`. This approach also allows you to use other fields e.g. `/rentals?sort=anotherField`.

Comment: Seriously amazing answer. Thanks a ton for the help.