# mongo-> how to fetch records on datetime desc order from two different collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collection coin1 & coin2, i am trying to fetch records from both collections on the base of date field order by DESC. where coin_id is 1

coin1 collection

```
[{ "_id" : 1, "coin_id" : "1", date: "1516259613150"},
{ "_id" : 2, "coin_id" : "1", date: "1514113680"}]
```

coin2 collection

```
[{ "_id" : 1, "coin_id" : "1", date: "1496836604"},
{ "_id" : 2, "coin_id" : "1", date: "1514113680"},
]]
```

I am looking result like this-:

```
[{ "_id" :1, "coin_id" : "1", date: "1516259613150"},
{ "_id" : 2, "coin_id" : "1", date: "1514113680"}.
{ "_id" : 1, "coin_id" : "1", date: "1514113680"},
{ "_id" : 2, "coin_id" : "1", date: "1496836604"}]
```

How can i get this records.

here date is in unix date format.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Mongoose, how do I sort by date? (node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825520/in-mongoose-how-do-i-sort-by-date-node-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you user mongoose, I think you can try like this code!

```
Collection.find().sort({'data':'( - or + )1'}).find(function (err, collection){
                   console.log(collection);
       });
```

Comment: thanks but i want to fetch records from both collections on one query.

Comment: I think you can use find() twice. callback in callback

Comment: Collection1.find().sort({'data':'( - or + )1'}).find(function (err, collection1){
                   Collection2.find().sort({'data':'( - or + )1'}).find(function (err, collection2){
                    // now you can use 2 collections collection1, collection2                                         console.log(collection1,collection2)   
       }); 
       });

Comment: but in that above code you use two different variables coll1 and coll2 , but my requirement is merge data of both collection into one array according to their desc order.