# How to filter an array of objects in mongoose by date field only selecting the most recent date

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to filter through an array of objects in a user collection on MongoDB. The structure of this particular collection looks like this:

```
name: "John Doe"
email: "john@doe.com"
progress: [
        {
         _id : ObjectId("610be25ae20ce4872b814b24")
         challenge: ObjectId("60f9629edd16a8943d2cab9b")
         date_unlocked: 2021-08-05T12:15:32.129+00:00
         completed: true
         date_completed: 2021-08-06T12:15:32.129+00:00
        }
        {
         _id : ObjectId("611be24ae32ce4772b814b32")
         challenge: ObjectId("60g6723efd44a6941l2cab81")
         date_unlocked: 2021-08-06T12:15:32.129+00:00
         completed: true
         date_completed: 2021-08-07T12:15:32.129+00:00
        }
]
date: 2021-08-04T13:06:34.129+00:00
```

How can I query the database using mongoose to return only the challenge with the most recent 'date_unlocked'?

I have tried: User.findById(req.user.id).select('progress.challenge progress.date_unlocked').sort({'progress.date_unlocked': -1}).limit(1);

but instead of returning a single challenge with the most recent 'date_unlocked', it is returning the whole user progress array.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Mongoose, how do I sort by date? (node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825520/in-mongoose-how-do-i-sort-by-date-node-js)

Comment: @zr0gravity7 I have updated my question with my attempt to query the database. I have tried using sort and limit with no joy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```json
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$progress"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "progress.date_unlocked": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 1
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "latestChallenge": "$progress.challenge"
    }
  }
])
```

[Test the code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p42dIA3yLDz)

Alternative solution is to use `$reduce` in that array.

```json
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "latestChallenge": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": "$progress",
              "initialValue": [
                "0",
                ""
              ],
              "in": {
                "$let": {
                  "vars": {
                    "info": "$$value",
                    "progress": "$$this"
                  },
                  "in": {
                    "$cond": [
                      {
                        "$gt": [
                          "$$progress.date_unlocked",
                          {
                            "$arrayElemAt": [
                              "$$info",
                              0
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      [
                        {
                          "$arrayElemAt": [
                            "$$info",
                            0
                          ]
                        },
                        "$$progress.challenge"
                      ],
                      "$$info"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "latestChallenge": 1
    }
  },
])
```

[Test the code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/a1ALGvgO8bU)

Mongoose can use raw MQL so you can use it.