# How do I limit the number of returned items?

Tags: mongoose

```
myModel.find({}, function(err, items) {
    console.log(items.length);    // Big number
});
```

How can I limit  the returned items to only the latest 10 items that were inserted?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

In the latest mongoose (3.8.1 at the time of writing), you do two things differently: (1) you have to pass single argument to sort(), which must be an array of constraints or just one constraint, and (2) execFind() is gone, and replaced with exec() instead. Therefore, with the mongoose 3.8.1 you'd do this:

```
var q = models.Post.find({published: true}).sort({'date': -1}).limit(20);
q.exec(function(err, posts) {
     // `posts` will be of length 20
});
```

or you can chain it together simply like that:

```
models.Post
  .find({published: true})
  .sort({'date': -1})
  .limit(20)
  .exec(function(err, posts) {
       // `posts` will be of length 20
  });
```

Comment: what does {'date': -1} mean? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ArslArsl - the results will be sorted by the date in decending order.

Comment: @ArslArsl it is similar to the following: `{ date: 'desc' }` `{date: 'descending'}`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299991/how-to-sort-in-mongoose)

Comment: Is there a max for limit?

Comment: I would suggest to do .sort({ createdAt: -1 }) if you want to sort by document creation time

Answer (score 34):

I am a bit lazy, so I like simple things:

```
let users = await Users.find({}, null, {limit: 50});
```

Answer (score 28):

Like this, using .limit():

```
var q = models.Post.find({published: true}).sort('date', -1).limit(20);
q.execFind(function(err, posts) {
  // `posts` will be of length 20
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know you could make queries like that.  Where can I find some form of documentation about this execFind method ?

Comment: Honestly, I just look at the examples in the mongoose sources and stuff, as well as the test cases. The mailing list is also good. The actual docs seem a bit out of date.

Comment: is execFind still in the latest version of mongoosejs?

Comment: @Manny It's not.  See the marni's answer for an updated version.

Answer (score 10):

```
models.Post.find({published: true}, {sort: {'date': -1}, limit: 20}, function(err, posts) {
 // `posts` with sorted length of 20
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 6):

**Find parameters**

The parameters find function takes are as follows:

1. conditions `«Object»`.
2. [projection] `«Object|String»` optional fields to return, see [Query.prototype.select()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select)
3. [options] `«Object»` optional see [Query.prototype.setOptions()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-setOptions)
4. [callback] `«Function»`

**How to limit**

```js
const Post = require('./models/Post');

Post.find(
  { published: true }, 
  null, 
  { sort: { 'date': 'asc' }, limit: 20 },
  function(error, posts) {
   if (error) return `${error} while finding from post collection`;

   return posts; // posts with sorted length of 20
  }
);
```

**Extra Info**

Mongoose allows you to query your collections in different ways like:
[Official Documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

```js
// named john and at least 18
MyModel.find({ name: 'john', age: { $gte: 18 }});

// executes, passing results to callback
MyModel.find({ name: 'john', age: { $gte: 18 }}, function (err, docs) {});

// executes, name LIKE john and only selecting the "name" and "friends" fields
MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, 'name friends', function (err, docs) { })

// passing options
MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, null, { skip: 10 })

// passing options and executes
MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, null, { skip: 10 }, function (err, docs) {});

// executing a query explicitly
var query = MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, null, { skip: 10 })
query.exec(function (err, docs) {});

// using the promise returned from executing a query
var query = MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, null, { skip: 10 });
var promise = query.exec();
promise.addBack(function (err, docs) {});
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason I could not get this to work with the proposed answers, but I found another variation, using select, that worked for me:

```
models.Post.find().sort('-date').limit(10).select('published').exec(function(e, data){
        ...
});
```

Has the api perhaps changed? I am using version 3.8.19

Answer (score 2):

...additionally make sure to use:

```
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
```

This sets the mongoose promise to the native ES6 promise. Without this addition I got:

> DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html