# How can I implement limit from to in mongoose same we do in mysql?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a pagination api in mongoose where I need to implement limit start and end, how can I achieve this is mongoose?

Comment: Please, can you add example from mysql? So question will be more clear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830513/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-returned-items

Comment: Use `skip` (offset) and `limit` (limit)

Comment: Thanks Now its working.