# Plain object mongoose not work with sort

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I need plain javascript object instead of mongoose object.

**Query**

```
chatModel.find({'userId':userId},{
            "_id":0,"message":1,"type":1            
           }).sort({createdDateISO:-1})
          .lean().exec((err,result)=>{
      });
```

But I will get mongoose object when I remove the `sort()` I am getting the plain javascript object.
How do i get the plain object with sort??

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299991/how-to-sort-in-mongoose

Comment: But its about the different sort() methods not about the plain object

Answer (score 0):

Passing options (in this case return the raw js objects, **not mongoose documents** by passing `lean`.So you cant use lean with sort(only use with mongoose document)