# Sorting is not working correcly with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a problem like this. I am making an API with express. In there, I have created a MongoDB connection using mongoose. In this API I have created a function to sort elements by date. This is my function is looks,

```
module.exports.findAll = function (callback) {
    const query = {state: "Confirmed"};
    Reservation.find(query, {sort: '-date'} , callback);
}
```

When I check this with POSTMan, it just returns the ids of particular elements.

This is my controller file.

```
const express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var  Reservation  = require('../models/reservation');

router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    Reservation.findAll(function (err, reservations) {
        if(err) throw err;

        if (!reservations){
            res.json({state:false,msg:"No reservations found"});
        }

        if(reservations){
            res.json(reservations);
        }

    })
});

router.post("/create",function (req,res) {
    const newReservation = new Reservation({
        date: req.body.date,
        from: req.body.from,
        to: req.body.to,
        lab: req.body.lab,
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        role: req.body.role,
        year: req.body.year,
        reason: req.body.reason,
        state: "Not Comfirm"
    });

    Reservation.saveReservation(newReservation, function (err, reservation) {
        if (reservation) {
            res.send(reservation);
        }

        else {
            console.log('Error in User save :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
        }
    });

});

router.get('/notComfirmed', function (req, res) {
    Reservation.findNotComfirmed(function (err, reservations) {
        if(err) throw err;

        if (!reservations){
            res.json({state:false,msg:"No reservations found"});
        }

        if(reservations){
            res.json(reservations);
        }

    })
});

router.post('/confirm', function(req, res){
    const _id= req.body._id;
    Reservation.updateReservation(_id, function (err, reservation) {
        if(err) throw err;

        if (!reservation){
            res.json({state:false,msg:"Something went wrong"});
        }

        if(reservation){
            res.json(reservation);
        }
    })
});

router.post('/remove', function(req, res){
    const _id= req.body._id;
    Reservation.remove(_id, function (err, reservation) {
        if(err) throw err;

        if (!reservation){
            res.json({state:false,msg:"Something went wrong"});
        }

        if(reservation){
            res.json(reservation);
        }
    })
});


module.exports = router;
```

This is how  my model  looks,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var DateOnly = require('dateonly');
const schema = mongoose.Schema;

const reservationSchema = new schema({
    date:{type:String, required:true},
    from:{type:String, reason:true},
    to:{type:String, required:true},
    lab:{type:String, required:true},
    name:{type:String, required:true},
    email:{type:String, required:true},
    role:{type:String, required:true},
    year:{type:String},
    reason:{type:String, required:true},
    state:{type:String, required:true},
});

const Reservation = module.exports= mongoose.model("Reservation",reservationSchema );

module.exports.saveReservation = function (newReservation, callback) {
    newReservation.date=new DateOnly(newReservation.date);
    newReservation.save(callback);
}


module.exports.findBYDateAndTime = function(date, time, lab, callback){
    const query = {date:date,time:time, lab:lab};
    Reservation.findOne(query,callback);
}

module.exports.findNotComfirmed= function (callback) {
    const query = {state: "Not Comfirm"};
    Reservation.find(query, callback);
}

module.exports.updateReservation = function (id, callback) {
    var reservation ={
        state: "Confirmed"
    }
    Reservation.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: reservation}, {new: true}, callback) ;
}

module.exports.remove = function (_id, callback) {
    Reservation.findByIdAndRemove(_id, callback);
}

module.exports.findAll = function (callback) {
    const query = {state: "Confirmed"};
    Reservation.find(query, {sort: '-date'} , callback);
}
```

Can someone, help me to get all the details of confirmed reservation with sort them by the date? I done it so many ways but it always returns only the ids of those reservations.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mongoose query, second parameter is reserved for fields which we want to select from mongodb.

I have found some answer on stackoverflow [How to sort in mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299991/how-to-sort-in-mongoose)

Try this one

`Reservation.find({}, null, {sort: {date: -1}}, function(err, docs) { ... });`