# Mongoose sort doesn't work as find option

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

## User Collection

```
[
  {
    username: 'user1'
  },
  {
    username: 'user2'
  },
  {
    username: 'user3'
  }
]
```

### Sorting by sort method

```
const users = await User.find({}).sort({username: -1});
console.log(users[0].username);
```

### Output

```
user3
```

### Sorting by options of find method

```
const users = await User.find({}, null, {sort: {username: -1}});
console.log(users[0].username);
```

### Output

```
user1
```

It's the same in mongodb console.
I don't know why it doesn't work. 
I referenced from '[How to sort in mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299991/how-to-sort-in-mongoose)'

#### Partial the answer

```
...
Post.find({}).sort('test').exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Post.find({}).sort([['date', -1]]).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Post.find({}).sort({test: 1}).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Post.find({}, null, {sort: {date: 1}}, function(err, docs) { ... });
```

Comment: I've tried on version `6.11.3` it's working, it shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @srinivasy I used mongoose v5.8.9, mongo v4.0.6. What does the version mean for?

Comment: it's mongoose version, usually you code should work, just set `mongoose.set('debug', true)` in the file where you're doing mongoose operation & check the query being sent to DB, Also test it once again..