# Displaying only the most recent mongoose timestamp?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I have an HTML table populated with MongoDB data. I used mongoose timestamps to display a date and time for any time a DB entry is updated.

I only want the most recent date/time to be displayed, instead of a date/time for each entry that gets updated (which is currently happening because of the `forEach` loop).

I'm not super familiar with mongoose so I'm wondering if there's a way to check for the most recent `<%= environment.updatedAt %>` and only display that one?

HTML:

```html
<table>
   <% environments.forEach(function(environment){ %>

    <%= environment.updatedAt =>

     <tr>
         <td><%= environment.ePIMS %></td>
         <td><%= environment.codeVersion %></td>
         <td><%= environment.region %></td>
     </tr>

   <% }); %> 
 </table>
```

let me know if you'd like to see my mongoose schema or anything else. thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the most recent updateAt after the table, assign it to a variable during the loop, and display it later.  Assuming `updateAt` is numeric, that might look like

```
<%= newest = Math.max(newest, environment.updatedAt) =>
```

If you want the most recent time to be displayed first, or in each row, one option is to find the newest with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like

```
<%=  environments.reduce(function(a,v){return Math.max(a,v.updatedAt)},0) =>
```

Or you could sort the query by `updateAt: -1` when retrieving the data so the newest is the first element.

Comment: thank you!! I went withsorting by ```updatedAt: -1``` to get the first one to always be the latest. I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/31824896/11099263 as a reference for how to sort in mongoose, if anyone was wondering