# How to sort in mongoose by specific order?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have Mongoose model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const { Schema } = mongoose

const schema = new Schema({
    Name: { type: String }, 
    Category: { type: String },
    Price: { type: Number } 
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', schema)
```

And I have to sort by Category field. Sort order is

```
['Clothes', 'Accessories', 'Footwears']
```

How cat I do it?

Comment: I mean How CAN I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort in mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299991/how-to-sort-in-mongoose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding weight of Category. Now my model is like this:

```
const schema = new Schema({
    Name: { type: String }, 
    Category: { type: String },
    CategoryWeight: { type: Number }, 
    Price: { type: Number } 
})
```

And I sorting like this:

```
const products = await Product.find().sort('-CategoryWeight')
```

Answer (score 1):

The MongoDB server doesn't offer any way to provide a custom sort function.

Javascript does, so you can get the results from the query as an array, and use a custom compare function with [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Thank you about your reply. I solved it by creating new value as CategoryWeight. And when i save it, i set weight