# Mongoose sort when field name contains whitespace?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to sort by a field with whitespace in the name, what is the workaround for this?

Query:

```
this.query = this.query.sort("Review Score");
```

Model:

```
["Review Score"]: {
  type: String,
},
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299991/how-to-sort-in-mongoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ascending:

```js
this.query = this.query.sort({ "Review Score": 1 });
```

For descending:

```js
this.query = this.query.sort({ "Review Score": -1 });
```