# Mongoose, how to sort the Date of a selected object inside a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have this mongoose schema where I want to sort menus items according to their createdAt field

```
user:
...
menus: [
{
  name: { type: String },
  recipes: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Recipe',
    },
  ],
  image: {
    url: { type: String },
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: avatarTypes,
    }
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now
  }
},
```

],

and in nodeJs when I fetch them I want to sort them according the createdAt in the menus (latest first)

and this is my code but it's not working

```
const menus = await User.findOne({
  _id: id,
}).sort('-menus.createdAt')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort in mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299991/how-to-sort-in-mongoose)

Comment: @Joe no. I tried

Comment: `createdAt` is a top-level field, you don't need `menus.` in front of it.