# Sorting in mongoose Express does not sort properly

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose

I need help with sorting in Express working with mongooose db.
When i use sort({'price':1}) everythink is good, but when i pass JSON.stringify(sort) which contains and logs out {"price":1} it stops working. Any ideas why?

```
     if(req.query.sortOption){
    const str = req.query.sortOption.split(':');
    sort[str[0]] = str[1] === 'desc' ? -1:1;
  }


  console.log(JSON.stringify(sort));
//here logs out {"price":-1} which works when i pass it into sort function as a string

  try {
    const annoucements = await Annoucement.find(query)
      .skip(page * annoucementsPerPage)
      .limit(annoucementsPerPage)
      .populate('author')
      .sort(JSON.stringify(sort))
    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'Successfully got an annoucement',
      results: annoucements.length,
      data: {
        annoucements,
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      status: 'Failed to get all annoucements',
      message: error,
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to sort in mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299991/how-to-sort-in-mongoose)

.sort() takes in an object, and does not take in a string. You used JSON.stringify(sort), which made the `sort` query into a string, hence mongoose could not parse it.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:
You should just pass `.sort(sort)` instead of transforming the object to a string.

**Explanation:**

Mongoose either accepts

- a string like `"price"` (for ascending order) or `"-price"` (for descending order).
- an array (not applicable in this case)
- an object, where the key is the property name and the value is the order (`1`, `"asc"`, `"ascending"` or `-1`, '"desc"`,` "descending"`)

What you did was basically pass the **string** value `"{price:-1}"` to it, which does not match any of the use cases. Therefore your sorting does not work as expected.